# Error on attempt to create named pipe using VBScript

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, named-pipes

I'm trying to create named pipe using VBScript on win7.
This is my code (took from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943564/2018010)):

```vb
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("\\.\pipe\PipeName", True)
a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
a.Close
```

But i got an error (manual translate, so may be not accurate):

```
test.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found
```

Same code with ordinary text file works fine:

```vb
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(".\\PipeName", True)
```

But, when i tried to escape backslashes:

```vb
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeName", True)
```

I got:

```
test.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found
```

**UPD:** I run script as administrator.

**UPD2:** I'm found another solution for my problem without using pipes, so my question is a little outdated, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I think the answer to the question you're referencing assumes that the pipe already exists

Comment: I tried some random names, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a named pipe server called 'PipeName'? This code works for me (I named my pipe 'HelloWorld'):

**C# Server:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("HelloWorld"))
    {
        pipe.WaitForConnection();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipe);
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**VBScript Client:**

```
Dim fs, pipe
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set pipe = fs.OpenTextFile("\\.\pipe\HelloWorld", 8, False, 0)
pipe.WriteLine("This is my message")
pipe.Close
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create a pipe from C/C#/pascal/etc? I wanted to use pipe to redirect input, output and error streams of console application and had assumed that i can create a pipe from VBS.

Comment: Yes, unless you can find a way to create the pipe from VBScript. Unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with named pipe from VBScript. I failed to create named pipe by `fso.CreateTextFile("\\.\pipe\MyPipe")`.

But I successfully connected from VBScript from with Pipe created by classical application:

Pipe was created by such code (pascal):

```
procedure OpenTestPipe;

var
 i,hOut: Integer;

begin

  hOut:=CreateNamedPipe('\\.\pipe\Test.htm',PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,1024,1024,NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,nil);

  i:=FileWrite(hOut,'Hello'#13#10,7);

MessageBox(0,'Pipe is opened','Pipe sample',0);

  FileClose(hOut);

end;
```

When MessageBox was shown I opened VBScript

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

MsgBox fso.OpenTextFile("\\.\pipe\test.htm",1).readLine
```

And got a message Hello

Comment: Thanks for idea, but i don't want want to write binary module for wix to do this.